# Как сделать так, чтобы ссылки не смещались?

Tags: html

Как сделать так, чтобы при сужении браузера ссылки не меняли своего места, а оставались на своем месте. Вот [сайт](http://zaday-voprosik.ru.preview.ihc.ru/) - сузьте браузер и ссылки сместятся.

Comment: На масштабе 20% вообще феерия происходит))

По теме - `min-width` контейнеру со ссылками задайте. Или `position: absolute;`

Comment: Не по теме - лучше будет просто "Задай Вопрос" безу РУ) ато выходит типа Задай Во просру))) сори за юмор)

Comment: аахахха..понял))

Comment: @Sh4dow заметил сходство с контактом? :)

@Palmervan  я вообще только про сру и прочитал :)

Comment: да, сходство с контактом есть - не отрицаю, так, как я не "дизайнер", а вот тут-то и контактик оказался рядом, но люди в дальнейшем смогут себе поменять дизайн.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `.top_menu` добавить CSS свойство `margin: 0px auto;`

**UPD:** А еще лучше убрать везде `<center> </center>`, ибо это ГК и позиционировать все так как указано выше!

А еще лучше создать `1 div` типа `id="wrapper"` и позиционировать его так как указано выше, тогда весь сайт будет по центру если в этот `div` заключить весь html!

А еще лучше хорошо учить html и css)))

Comment: непомогло((

Comment: Сочувствую))

Comment: Исходя из логики наверное был выбран сразу же лучший предложенный вариант - "хорошо учить html и css". Два часа потратил на учебу и не помогло?))) Я думаю нужна небольшая поправка - хорошо учить html и css в течении 3-∞ месяцев))

Comment: @culebre  -- ты прям гуру.

Comment: Не бери близко к сердцу, не хотел обидеть.

Comment: @culebre да я и не обижался ☺, каким ты пользовался сочитанием клавиш для вставки знака бесконечности??

Comment: стандартные->служебные->таблица символов. Учитывая количество знаков предоставляемых кодировками UTF, я предпологаю, что очень малая часть представлена комбинациями, причем в linux(по крайней мере в консоли) с этим дела обстоят чуть лучше чем в винде, хотя не берусь утверждать на 100% - быть может равноценно.

Answer (score 0):

Задайте контейнеру ссылок в стилях `min-width:100500px` либо `white-space:nowrap`.